# Can snowsql be configured to run a login.sql script and NOT exit?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

[edit] now using snowsql Version: 1.2.10

When invoking snowsql with either the **-q** or **-f** options, a statement or sql file can be executed. In both of my test cases -- a statement or sql file -- they **DO NOT** contain an 'exit' yet snowsql exits the connection, returning me to the o/s prompt.

Ideally I want to run 1 or more queries immediately on starting snowsql and then still be connected and at the snowsql prompt. (Functionality like Oracle's login.sql behavior.)

For example, I'd like to be able to alter my session automatically on login. e.g.

```
alter session set query_tag='my-tag';
```

Answer (score 0):

A two step approach would be:

1. Connect through SnowSQL
2. run `!source <filename>`

This will execute the SQL in the file without exiting SnowSQL.

> I thought using the **-q** parameter would work. For me it didn't work and returned the following error after connecting:
>
> > 001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
> >     syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected '/'.
>
> I need to investigate further as I don't have a '/' in my file

Comment: While that works interactively -- like you said, your suggestion is a 2 step approach -- I'm looking for something that runs immediately upon calling snowsql. I'll go further and say "automatically" at execution of snowsql.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to configure Snowsql to keep the client session active? 
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/snowsql-config.html#client-session-keep-alive

Comment: Thumbs up for the reference. I tested this to be sure. Thumbs down because it doesn't address the key issue of staying logged in immediately after execution of the script during snowsql login.